# Responsive Background CSS Landing

Tags: html, css, background, frontend, responsive

Good Afternoon
Trying to make responsive background on my landing, and for some reason i couldn't
I was trying to use height: auto, height: 100% and margin: 0 auto; The height 100% worked but it didn't cover to down of my screen, i had it more than i need. 
Here is my code:

```
    .crossfade > figure {
  animation: imageAnimation 48s linear infinite 0s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 470px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 189px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  background-blend-mode: darken;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

The only one thing worked for me, it was:

```
height: calc(100vh - 189px);
```

189px it indent from my header menu, but is any how i can make it work without calc? 
Hope you undertand what i meant
Thanks

Comment: add your html code.

Comment: here is the web page https://www.daotech.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
.crossfade > figure { 
  animation: imageAnimation 48s linear infinite 0s; 
  background-size: cover; 
  background-position: center center; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100vh; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left:0; 
  right:0; 
  bottom:0; 
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3); 
  z-index: 0; 
}

#menu-contact-us { 
  background: #5D5D5D; 
  height: 124px; 
  color: #ffffff; 
  width: 100%; 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 1; 
}
```

I was able to get the images to go full screen on the link that you posted

Comment: Thank you for help but i don't need fixed background, it has to be just responsive, but when you slide down, it stays in his place. You can look up here for example https://www.citelectronics.com/ but its hard for me to do this with menu on the top of my web page :(

Comment: I updated the code to use position: absolute and with a z-index on the menu to make it go over the image, you might need that z-index on other elements too

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.crossfade > figure {
  animation: imageAnimation 48s linear infinite 0s;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: It kind of help me but background covered my menu on the top of my web page

Comment: So try to play with the z-index